# What is the difference between an I/MM, E/MM and H/MM package?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, microchip

I'm looking into the PIC18F25K80 as a new microcontroller for my company, but ran into an issue with supplier quantities. The PIC18F25K80-I/MM-ND that I originally selected seems to be very hard to find. On both Digikey and Mouser, quantities are limited and lead times are long. But I noticed that Mouser has a large quantity of the PIC18F25K80-E/MM-ND.

When I do a comparison of these 3 microcontrollers, I get almost no difference, and maybe none at all. Mouser says the H/MM has slightly more RAM, while Digikey says the H/MM has a narrower voltage range.

Here is the [comparison link on Digikey's site](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/compare/en?returnUrl=%2Fproduct-search%2Fen%3Fvendor%3D0%26keywords%3D18f25k80&part=PIC18F25K80-I%2FMM-ND&part=PIC18F25K80-E%2FMM-ND&part=PIC18F25K80-H%2FMM-ND).

What is the actual difference between these 3? They are all 28QFN, are all based on the 18F25K80 chip, but have different pricing and different availability.

And which one is the "main" chip? I'm trying to replace the PIC18F2580 in a large number of our products, but am worried about availability on the 18F25K80 and just want to get a standard 28QFN IC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I see an "I" suffix on a part I can usually guess it indicates a part qualified for the "industrial" temperature range, and sure enough that's what it indicates on this part:

[image]

Incidentally, I had to go to microchip.com and download the "High-Temperature Datasheet" to get this information, as the H suffix wasn't listed in the datasheet at octopart.

Sometimes a part qualified on a wider temperature range might be restricted to a narrower voltage, like you found for this part. You'll need to review the high-temperature datasheet to see if the H suffix has any performance restrictions that affect your application. The fact that they issued a separate datasheet for it rather than revising the main datasheet implies there's likely some differences in the performance specs.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely answers the question. And since my companies products never exceed 85F at the MCU and have a stable 5v VCC, the three are essentially interchangeable for me.

Comment: 85C. Not F. They regularly go above 85F. Typing is not my strong suit right now it seems.